# Jackson - Deserialise Different Date formats

Tags: java, jackson

i am using JsonDeserializer to format my Date as below:

```
public class CustomDateMappingDeserialize extends JsonDeserializer<Date>{

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser paramJsonParser, DeserializationContext paramDeserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String date = paramJsonParser.getText();
            try {
                Date formattedDate= format.parse(date);
              return formattedDate;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

    }

}
```

but the problem is i have to **define the Format fixed here** and  i have many different date formats.

Can we do something like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateMappingDeserialize.class, format ="yyy-dd-mm")
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

Instead of defining it in Custom class ?

Any help/pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a previous requirement of similar nature i had used multi parser options as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563155/gson-to-json-conversion-with-two-dateformat/18337283#18337283).

Following similar lines , the following custom class is an example

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

public class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    private static final String[] DATE_FORMATS = new String[] { "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd, yyyy" };

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser paramJsonParser, DeserializationContext paramDeserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (paramJsonParser == null || "".equals(paramJsonParser.getText()))
            return null;
        String date = paramJsonParser.getText();

        for (String format : DATE_FORMATS) {
            try {
                return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US).parse(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Edit :

You can also use additional libraries as outlined by suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597959/best-method-for-parsing-date-formats-during-import-datas/39598609?noredirect=1#comment66509764_39598609) using MultiDateTimeParsers.